# Linq to SQL Left Join with where clause looking for condition or null

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I need to select records from 2 tables, with a left join.  That part is fine.  However, in the where clause, I need to select `where t2.fromDate > 20190101 OR t2.fromDate is null`.

The problem is that in c#, the `t2.fromDate` is an `int`, not a nullable int. How should I compare `t2.fromDate` to null?  I've tried `t2.fromDate == 0`, but that doesn't work, because in SQL the value is null, but in C# is expects the value to be an int.

```
int FromDate = 20190101;
var data = (from hi in DbContext.t1
        from fp in DbContext.t2.Where(x => x.DimHierarchyItemKey == hi.Key).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where fp.fromDate >= FromDate || ???
```

Comment: Can't you update your entity to be `int?` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I don't have control over the db schema, and the C# pocos are created dynamically so any changes I make I'd have to make post regen every time.

Comment: If `t2.fromDate` is an `int`, it is impossible for it be `null` in C#, so you can just always assume it is not null. If a null value is attempted to be instantiated, you well get an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was easier than I expected.

```
int FromDate = 20190101;
var data = (from hi in DbContext.t1
        from fp in DbContext.t2
                .Where(x => x.DimHierarchyItemKey == hi.Key).DefaultIfEmpty()
                .Where(x => x.fromDate>= FromDate).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1. If `fp.OrderedDimDateKey` is nullable in the database it should also be nullable in the entity.
2. (Your case, I guess) If `fp.OrderedDimDateKey` is not nullable in the database the only way for it to be null in your query is when there is no matching `t2` entity. Which means that the test can be carried out as

   ```cs
   where fp.OrderedDimDateKey >= FromDate || fp == null
   ```

Comment: Thank you, @GertArnold!  I'll try that next.  The way I have works, but I never thought about your way.  I'll test it out later.  Thank you for your suggestion.